# Jira Python API Transitions

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I'm trying to use the Python Jira API to set transition fields but I can't seem to get it through the API call. Some transitions have required fields and I want to be able to add comment/change some of the fields. However, the API isn't giving me the list of required fields for each transition. Some of them have no fields and I have no problem transitioning with those transitions. However, for some transitions like ***Clean***, there are fields inside before you complete the transition. For example, I want to be able to change the resolution for this transition from ***Fixed*** to ***Won't Fix***. I can change it manually by looking at the values and doing the transition with the value I want, but this is not ideal. I want to be able to look at all the possible values and be able to choose whichever one the user wants to pick for the resolution.
[image]

I'm using this code from the JIRA Python API which gives me all the names but not any of the required fields and the values associated with the fields.

```
issue = jira.issue('PROJ-1')
transitions = jira.transitions(issue)
[(t['id'], t['name']) for t in transitions]
```

Answer (score 4):

To get all the fields, you need to add this.

```
transitions = jira.transitions(issue, expand="transitions.fields")
```